# What do I need to add to the Facebook Page Plugin, showing the page posts, so that the videos in the posts will play?

Tags: facebook, video, plugins

I am trying to use the Facebook Page Plugin, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/, including the page posts. Any videos that appear in the posts do NOT play.

The website where I have added the plugin is hosted by Main Street sites. I added the JavaScript SDK code to the site options, global content, after body section.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I added the plugin code to the home page:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MusicTogetherBR?fref=ts" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/MusicTogetherBR?fref=ts"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MusicTogetherBR?fref=ts">Music Together of Bay Ridge</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

Has anyone else tried this and experienced the same issue? Is it possible to get the videos to play?

Thank you.

Comment: There’s no specific options for that plugin to achieve this. So either they did deliberately not implement this, or forgot or messed something up. Go file a bug report and request clarification.

Comment: Where is the best place to file a bug report? I tried at the Facebook developers site, but I had to enter a Facebook app and I'm not developing a Facebook app, so it wouldn't let me submit my report.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug. I went ahead and filed one on your behalf. Here's the link - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/994234910609982/. Please subscribe to the bug and we'll provide an update there.

UPDATE: This should now be fixed. Can you please check and let us know if it's not working correctly ?